# how to play video fro two specific time in video view in android

Tags: android

```
  myVideoView.setVideoPath(filePath);
        myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        myVideoView.requestFocus();
        myVideoView.seekTo(startTImeData[0]* 1000);
        myVideoView.start();
        Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(stopPlayerTask, endTimeData[0] * 1000);

    }

    Runnable stopPlayerTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

                trackingVideoPlayTime();
        }
    };

   public void trackingVideoPlayTime(){
        // this will always till video play ... update time according to need if required update it to second by second or min or hour
        int playTime = myVideoView.getCurrentPosition()/1000;
Q
        // comparing playtime with  start_skip_time.length
        int a=1;
        while(a>startTImeData.length){
            if(playTime==startTImeData[a]){
                myVideoView.stopPlayback();
                myVideoView.seekTo(endTimeData[a]* 1000);
                myVideoView.start();
                // play again at given time
                return;
            } else {
                // do nothing
            }
            a++;
        }
    }
```

This is my code i am trying to play  video from main video whose length is 20 second fro specific time  from 2-4 and 8-9 only means 2 second video but when i try to implement using my code its not working coz play time always gives main video size please suggest me where am doing wrong.